# deep learning for 3d segmentation

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, 3d, conv-neural-network, faster-rcnn

I have 20 heart images taken at the same location and there are 50 of those images. 
So, 20 images are one input and I have 50 inputs. 
Because heart is moving, all images are different.
I want to make those images as input and then segmented binary mask images as output using deep learning.

I treat my inputs as 3D and found a lot of 3D CNN or FCN online. But those are the case of x,y,z 3D.
My case is x, y, t.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you consider this problem as a 2D problem? You can use the sequences for removing non-moving unwanted parts of the images, then do your segmentation with a 2D model in each image separately.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to **video object segmentation**, where an object needs to be semantically segmented across several frames in a video by utilizing *temporal information* across frames. In your case, each set of input image can be thought of as a video with *20 frames* with dataset containing *50 videos* and you can use supervised, semi-supervised or unsupervised video object segmentation models (depending on the availability/cost of obtaining ground truth masks). This formulation solves the task of segmenting input image stack in `(x,y,t)` order with FCNs.

Below are references I found for research work related to video object segmentation:

- https://paperswithcode.com/task/video-object-segmentation
- https://paperswithcode.com/task/semi-supervised-video-object-segmentation
- https://paperswithcode.com/task/unsupervised-video-object-segmentation